# How to collect data from dynamic HTML table

Tags: php, html

I have a page with a HTML table with newsfacts (NIEUWSBERICHT), photos (IMAGE) and ads (RECLAME). On this page  the user can organize these items by adding a pagenumber to them. After saving the pagenumbers to the db, the items with a pagenumber will be broadcast in an edition of the cablenewspaper (or whatever you call it in English), which is the final goal. The HTML table also shows the foreign keys I need for my queries.

There's an image of the HTML table at:

[image]

My problem is: how can I collect the data from the above HTML table after submitting the form?

I want to get 2 types of queries like (for example; keys correspond with the above picture):

```
UPDATE NIEUWSBERICHT SET pagenumber = 2 WHERE nieuwsbericht_id = 53
UPDATE NIEUWSBERICHT SET pagenumber = 3 WHERE nieuwsbericht_id = 56
UPDATE NIEUWSBERICHT SET pagenumber = 6 WHERE nieuwsbericht_id = 62
```

and

```
UPDATE IMAGE SET pagenumber = 7 WHERE image_id = 19
```

What makes it difficult for me is that the HTML table is build up dynamically (in PHP) and the number of rows is variable. See listing below. Somehow I think it would be better if I let go of the dynamically building of the table and start using arrays to store all variables in instead of "$cell". Or maybe I can somehow get the PageNo-item in the screen get multiple values, like in the picture the PageNo on the first row gets the values 20 and 8, which I can use in the query. Aahhhrrg, I just don't know how to continue anymore. Anyone please?

```
// Get column names //
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
echo "<h1>Create edition {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
    {
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
    }
echo "<td>PageNo</td>";
echo "</tr>\n";

// Show query result //
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
echo "<tr>";
foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";
echo "<td> <select  name='paginanummer'>
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    </select></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    }
```

Wow, it's become quite a story. Hope I did it all right.

Comment: Having an HTML version of your table would be useful for giving you an exact code solution. One way people embed "live" code (vs. images) is to use a service like jsfiddle.net. Check it out -- pretty cool stuff. Also, a question: Can you use jQuery or should this be pure JS?

Comment: It's not very clear to me whether you want it to be a simple form that you process with PHP, or that it should be an AJAX call.

Comment: @RickKuipers good point. JiM_i, are you trying to read the results of a form via a php `$_POST` object or parse the values in the browser?

Comment: @editor: I think I will be using $_POST, although I'm not sure. Not that experienced. Hey and my picture is back. Thanks;-)

Comment: @Rick Kuipers: it's just a form to process with PHP, no AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

give the `select` elements name with the id of the row that it represents
for example:

```
 <select name="position_12">
```

for the row with id 12 on the db

than when the form is submitted,
loop over the data to search for the parameter that start with "position_"

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
  if(preg_match("^position\_(\d+)$",$key,$matches) && is_numeric($value)){
     $row_id = $matches[1];
      echo "insert {$value} into row number {$row_id}";
  }
}
```

where I put the `echo` line you have the `$row_id` and `$value` vars, that you can use to build your query

Comment: Thanks Yaron! I am going to work on this one. I'll get back when I have results!

Comment: Thanks again Yaron, my problem is solved! I used your first hint about the select name. I think I should post my code in a new answer, which I will be doing in a minute.

Comment: I can't even click your answer is useful because I need at least 15 reputation points for that, which I don't have. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Bingo, it works!

Here's the code for populating the HTML-table column "PageNo". As you can see I gave the select unique names (thanks to Yaron;-)) and I put the keys I need in the select's value, like a string.

```
echo "<td> <select  name='position_".$rowcounter."'>
   <option value='$type, $nieuwsbericht_id, $reclame_id, $image_id, 0'></option>
   <option value='$type, $nieuwsbericht_id, $reclame_id, $image_id, 1'>1</option>
   <option value='$type, $nieuwsbericht_id, $reclame_id, $image_id, 2'>2</option>
   <option value='$type, $nieuwsbericht_id, $reclame_id, $image_id, 3'>3</option>
   <option value='$type, $nieuwsbericht_id, $reclame_id, $image_id, 4'>4</option>
   <option value='$type, $nieuwsbericht_id, $reclame_id, $image_id, 5'>5</option>
   <option value='$type, $nieuwsbericht_id, $reclame_id, $image_id, 6'>6</option>
   <option value='$type, $nieuwsbericht_id, $reclame_id, $image_id, 7'>7</option>
   <option value='$type, $nieuwsbericht_id, $reclame_id, $image_id, 8'>8</option>
   <option value='$type, $nieuwsbericht_id, $reclame_id, $image_id, 9'>9</option>
   <option value='$type, $nieuwsbericht_id, $reclame_id, $image_id, 10'>10</option>
   </select></td>";
```

Then after submitting, the ten values are stored in an arrray called $kv. It goes like this:

```
if ($_POST) {
    $kv = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $kv[] = "$value";
    etc...
```

Then I loop through the array to split the values (strings) using splitdata into seperate variables. That's what I wanted! It goes like this:

```
$maxcount = count($kv) - 1;
for ($teller = 0; $teller <= $maxcount; $teller++) {
$data = $kv[$teller];
$splitdata = explode(',', $data);
$type = $splitdata[0];
$nieuwsbericht_id = $splitdata[1];
$reclame_id = $splitdata[2];
$image_id = $splitdata[3];
$paginanummer = $splitdata[4];

etc.... (now I can create the sql queries I need to update the database tables)
```